# How to show WPF DataGrid Parent/Child records with Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wpfdatagrid

I have been trying to find an example of how to create a WPF parent/child datagrid where the child records are displayed underneath the related parent row.  I am using the Entity Framework for aquiring the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have worked out the Bindings and the Columns stuff....

You can use the `RowDetails` to show more information about the Row....

For Example

```
<WPFToolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

    <WPFToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
              <!--Your Favourite Controls-->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </WPFToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```